# Nifi Content Repository format: performance on CSVRecordSetWritter vs AvroRecordSetWritter

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm currently tunning Nifi `ExecuteSQLRecord` ingestion. There are multiple aspects here, while in this question I'm interested in one: *how much ingestion speed is dependent on xxxSetWriter choice?*

AFAIK, from [Nifi in Depth: Content Repository](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/nifi-in-depth.html#content-repository), I understand Content Repository store the data in some binary format. *Then what is the difference between `CSVRecordSetWritter` and `AvroRecordSetWriter` in `ExecuteSQLRecord`? Does `ExecuteSQLRecord` convert result set to target format and then serialize it somehow? May performance depend significantly on the choice?*

I noticed that on big datasets changing `CSVRecordSetWritter` to `AvroRecordSetWriter` will save only 8-9% of data volume and win about 10-15% of `ExecuteSQLRecord` speed.

I'm pretty sure that SQL source and network *aren't* bottlenecks. Thread count, GC, number of nodes and cores and disk partitioning are *out of scope* for this question.

Answer (score 0):

The Content Repository stores the data in a binary format serializing the flowfile content, but that content is in one of the standard formats (Avro or CSV in your case). The "internal record representation" used by NiFi when performing record operations or conversions is only present in memory, and is not persisted to the content repository.

The specific implementation and performance cost of converting from the canonical record format returned by the SQL query and Avro or CSV is not something I know off the top of my head, you would have to perform benchmark testing to see which is better (although I expect CSV would be faster because Avro is a more complicated process).

If you've locked so many variables, really the only decision beyond "which format to write to" is the [scheduling of the processor execution](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#scheduling-tab) (run schedule, run duration, yield duration). I would try increasing the run duration to "perform more work" per "repository write" (the expensive operation).